# How to remove MDM policies when I don't even have any MDM listed?

Tags: windows, group-policy

Access work or school Windows is empty, I have nothing to disconnect.

Provisioning packages is also empty, nothing to do there.

And I have no Microsoft account.

I tried removing them via regedit, but they keep coming back and yet I have tens of random policies that includes: random updates without any notice and probably other malicious garbage, how do I get rid of them?

[Policies image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1tkv.png)

And empty options

[work and school](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oCwj.png)

[packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2XHc.png)

Answer (score 1):

> how do I get rid of them?

If you disable MDM enrollment it should solve your issue.  In order to do that you have to be an Administrator on the machine.

> Using the GP editor, the path is Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > MDM > Disable MDM Enrollment.
>
> [image]

You can find the registry key here:

> `\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MDM`
>
> Set `DisableRegistration` to **0**

Source: [Disable MDM Enrollment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/mobile-device-enrollment#disable-mdm-enrollments)

Comment: Disabled enrollment via regedit, restarted my PC and the MDM policies are still there

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user profile?  After you disabled MDM enrollment did you set each of the policies that had been set to not configured?

Comment: I created a fresh user profile, gave it administrator privileges and it still had the same MDM policies. Also not sure which policies you talking about, but looking at "User Config/Admin templates/All settings" everything is set to not configured even before doing anything

Comment: This doesn’t make sense; Was this machine previously connected to a active directory domain?

Comment: I think I did have an University account/domain listed under work/school but I already removed it

Comment: did you ever resolve this?